# Passing the entirety of the common variables to an invoke-command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

Recently I've been downloading powershell functions and scripts that I find useful and wrapping them into invoke-commands to make them more useful across my network. One thing I haven't figured out is how to accept the common parameters from the [cmdletBinding()] and pass them all into the invoke-command. I know how to pass individual preference variables but not the entirety of them. Is there a common variables collection? Below is some powershell excerpts to help illustrate.

```
ScriptBlock =
{   #How do I pass the whole of the common variables?
    $ErrorActionPreference=$using:ErrorActionPreference
    $InformationPreference=$Using:InformationPreference
    $VerbosePreference=$Using:VerbosePreference...

Process
{
    Write-Verbose "Processing"
    $computername=$name
    #Used $Name as a parameter originally to be compatible with the get-adcomputer cmdlet
    If ($Credential) {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock}
    Else {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock}
    #You will need to be running Powershell with the proper Admin privileges if you don't specify a credential
} #End Process
  END{
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the $PSBoundParameters hashtable.

```
$VerbosePreference=$PSBoundParameters['Verbose']
$ErrorActionPreference=$PSBoundParameters['ErrorAction']
```

EDIT:

You can also splat these standard parameters to your cmdlets as well

```
Invoke-Command -scriptblock $scriptblock @PSBoundParameters
```

Comment: The first option doesn't see to be any better than what I'm doing now.

Comment: The second option is closer to what I'm looking for. However, it errors out on me when I use it. I think this would only work if my parameters all matched what invoke-command expects. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that would be true. You can also construct a custom hashtable to store your variables in and splat them wherever you need. You could build it programmatically with `[System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet]::CommonParameters`

Comment: It worked! With a little tweaking of my script I got this to work. You made my script so sexy now. She will be the envy of all other scripts.

Comment: Awesome! Please don't forget to mark my answer helpful if that works for you.

Comment: I spoke too soon. When I removed the $using:$x declaration of my preference variables my verbose output vanished.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Do I need to be $using:@PSBoundParameters or whatever is equivalent?

Comment: The @ sign is the splat operator. This takes keys of a hashtable as named parameters and their values to a cmdlet. Like I said, you can construct a custom hashtable if you don't want to pass any of the other parameters, or the `System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet]::CommonParameters` static property will allow you to extract these in a simple foreach loop.

Comment: It seems like the @psboundparameter only carries the parameters I explicitly defined in my function. It doesn't seem to carry the stuff you get from [cmdletbinding()] like the -verbose and -debug switches. That is what I was hoping to pipe to my scriptblock without redefining all those variables. You have saved my from that ugly if statement in my Process section.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timid/2014/08/12/psboundparameters-and-commonparameters-whatif-debug-etc/

Comment: Thanks. You answered my question. It wasn't the answer I was looking for, but it was the I needed. Apparently, I can't do it as it stands now. I have to recreate each parameter in my script block that I want to re-use.

Comment: I wanted to mark your answer. However, my street cred apparently is not good enough. Sorry.